# When should "度" be used? When should "量" be used?

Tags: word-choice

I noticed both 度 and 量 mean "amount, number". It looks like they are not exchangeable. Am I right?

For example, I saw 温度，湿度，长度，宽度，高度，角度， but never saw 温量，湿量，长量，宽量，高量，角量。I also feel 重量，容量，含量，数量 are fixed combinations too. Is there a rule about where to use which?

Comment: 小马词典：量：capacity; quantity; amount;度： extent; degree of intensity;typical  examples 热量(heat),温度(temperature), more examples: 质量、力量、重量、产量、数量、含量、能量、、容量、流量
速度、程度、高度、强度、长度，浓度、密度、厚度、深度、宽度

Comment: **度**, 程**度**: degree, level, scale; **量**, 计**量**: measure, meterage, metric. 度 is used for ratio or value, 量 is used for volume of things generally, but it is not absolute, maybe the translation convention is different in different eras.

Comment: 热量 heat, 热度 temperature. more results showing how dictionaries distinguish between nouns 量 and 度:＂汉语水平考试词典＂：量（名）［义１］数量；数目（quantity):～变｜～词｜～器｜变～｜常～（constant; numeric constant）｜电～｜动～｜风～｜计～｜剂～｜流～｜微～｜限～｜度～衡（weights and measures）｜限雨～｜等～齐观（put on a par）｜一定要保质保～地完成任务｜这个港口的年吞吐～是八千万顿［义２］能够容纳或达到的限度（capacity):放～｜海～｜极～｜食～｜音～｜老张饭～很大，一顿可以吃三四碗｜男子汉气～不能太小，要大度一些。＄度（名）表明物质的有关性质达到的程度（degree of intensity):亮～｜热～｜硬～｜纯～｜广～｜宽～｜这辆车的速～真快｜那块板的后～正合适。［义２］表示可以计量的标准（degree)：进～｜坡～｜桥的跨～不太大｜做什么事都要适～，不要过～.

Comment: @賈可Jacky The more examples I read, the more I believe there is actually no rules to differ these two words.

Answer (score 1):

度 is measurement for length, height or level  (difference between levels is measured in distance )

量 is measurement for volume (something to do with space available or occupied)

As nouns, they are not interchangeable

量度 (v ) to measure ( length or volume)

量 (v) to measure ( length or volume)

度 (v) to measure ( length)

Comment: 度 is not just for measuring length. The counter examples are 温度，湿度，etc.

Comment: I mentioned 度 measuring 'level' -温度 and 湿度 are measuring in '高' (high) or '低' (low).  High is long length low is short length

Answer (score 0):

度 - measure length

量 - measure volume

衡 - measure weight